# How many role providers can I use with MOSS 2007?

Tags: 2007, role-provider

We have 2 master sites on MOSS 2007. We are using custom role provider with the sites and subsites under them.
Will it be possible to use different role provider with sub sites?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't configure multiple FBA providers in a single zone for the same webapplication.  To support multiple FBA authentication providers you will either need to create multiple Zones (one for each provider) or write a single custom provider that can pull the data from other sources .

Comment: When you quote other people, give them credit? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07341896-3e7e-4e77-a8d0-4fbc52bdfefc/one-fba-web-application-with-multiple-membership-providers#allReplies